# Options and template changes not updating

Tags: urls

Few months ago I had a problem with updating changes on wordpress, all changes were registered inside WP but in front end no changes were shown even if I change something manually on theme as footer or sidebars. I fixed that changing the htaccess because the htacces had written a different domain like `blogonline` instead `multionline.com`.

```
RewriteEngine off
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home/mainuser/public_html/blogonline.com/php.ini
    <Files php.ini>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Now I have the same problem but... all data is correct including this  lines for WP

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: Remove `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404`. What happens?

Comment: Do you have a caching plugin active?

Comment: I deactivate all plugins even super cache, I´m seen some changes after 2 hours... I think this is a cache issue, becuase theme switch also is affected; no changes are shown after removing line ERRORDOCUMENT 404; I will wait a little to refresh page again @vancoder